# PyCharm: Show local variables after exception in "Run"

Tags: pycharm

Most of the time I spent in PyCharm is executing tests with "Run" (shift-F10).

If the test fails with an exception, then it would be very nice if I could see/inspect the local variables.

Example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x_vums/src/dt/dt/tests/test_foo.py", line 150, in test_quotes_can_miss
    lines = list(cutils.read_c(string=t))
  File "/home/x_vums/src/dt/dt/utils/cutils.py", line 616, in read_c
    coln = [col.strip(quote_char + b' ') for col in splitted]
  File "/home/x_vums/src/dt/dt/utils/cutils.py", line 616, in <listcomp>
    coln = [col.strip(quote_char + b' ') for col in splitted]
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

In above example I would like to inspect which variable is a string and which is bytes.

I know how to debug in PyCharm, but "Run" is faster than "Debug".

I created a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37763

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is apparently a reason why there are two ways to start a program. ;-) I'm sure that the program started with "Run" is exited by the exception, and then all variables are lost.

However, you can add a `print` statement before the failing line and peek at the values yourself. This could be still faster than starting with "Debug" and waiting for the exception.

Comment: Why not make the future better then the current state of the art?

Comment: Then SO is the wrong place to ask for an enhancement of PyCharm; please visit JetBrains' web site and [submit a request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731).

Comment: How can I know if there is already a solution or if this is a feature request?

Comment: How about [asking JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm)? They are nice people answering quickly.

Comment: Here the question at the JetBrains support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004508100-PyCharm-Show-local-variables-after-exception-in-Run-